# The ring $\Bbb Q[x,y,z]/(x^a,y^b,z^c)$ is noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian, artinian

How to show the ring $\Bbb Q[x,y,z]/(x^a,y^b,z^c)$ is noetherian?
I know this ring is artin,and we can conclude the ring is artin because every ration ring is Noether.But I want to show this by definition of Noether ring.Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: any quotient of a Noetherian ring is Noetherian, and by Hilbert's basis theorem $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]$ is Noetherian

Comment: I accepted it.Thank you for your beautiful answer.

Comment: What is “actin”? I think it’s a typo for artin but it’s placement and the fact you spelled artin correctly later makes me wonder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Every ideal of $R=\mathbb Q[x,y,z]/(x^a,y^b,z^c)$ is a linear subspace of $R$, viewed as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$. Now, observe that $$\dim_{\mathbb Q}R=abc < \infty$$